# Javascript Date Format is displayed differently in Firefox for different locations

Tags: javascript, date, firefox, timezone-offset

I have a javascript code which constructs an HTML page.
The page has a table with a date column. The date format required is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM

In the Javascript I generate this format from below code.

Expected Output is 06/07/2019 **6:00:00 PM**

At my location when I run the javascript code in my machine located in India, I get the expected result.
But when the client runs it, at his system in the USA, he sees some offset in time.

It appears like mentioned below in Firefox.

6/06/2019 **2:00:00 04:00 PM**

What could be the reason for this? And how could I resolve it?

```
'<span>"06-06-2019 1:00:00 CDT PM".split('-')[1]+'/'+"06-06-2019 1:00:00 CDT PM".split('-')[0]+'/'+"06-06-2019 1:00:00 CDT PM".substr(6, 13).trim()+' '+"06-06-2019 1:00:00 CDT PM".substr(23)</span>'
```

Comment: It displays it in the format that the user expects, which depends on the location.

Comment: If you really want to do date formatting and manage offsets, use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Comment: @Barmar The user is expecting it to be in 06/07/2019 6:00:00 PM format without any offset

Comment: Show your code that's formatting the date. The code you showed has a hard-coded date, it can't produce the result you say.

Comment: @Barmar I am making an ajax call to the source to get this date in the json response which is later parsed using parseJSON.
Then, I would do a simple assignment to the variable.

var solutionImpDate=json[i]['solutionImpDate'];

And use this variable as mentioned in my hardcoded date value

Comment: Post your code, it's hard to tell what's actually going on from your description.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is **TimeZone** Difference. Every people have there own browser and Javascript work on a client side so it is but obvious nature of javascript it will show local date time by default.

you can simply set the value by setting a **timezone** offset value

```
Date.prototype.getUTCLocalDate = function () {
    var target = new Date(this.valueOf());
    var offset = target.getTimezoneOffset();
    var year = target.getUTCFullYear();
    var month = target.getUTCMonth();
    var date = target.getUTCDate();
    var hour = target.getUTCHours();
    var minutes = target.getUTCMinutes();
    var seconds = target.getUTCSeconds();
    return new Date(Date.UTC(year , month , date , hour , minutes + offset, seconds ));
  };
```

Or you can get a server time zone offset by making a rest query and make your own offset to show unique time in everywhere.

Comment: If i get the Date from the code which u mentioned above how will it remove the Offset which i see in the browser.   As you can see i am getting 6/06/2019 2:00:00 04:00 PM where it is 2hrs but i also have an offset of 04:00. WIll the browser automatically know that i am using UTC time?